# How to pass Array of Entities to Entity Repository and run `where in` query?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql, php-5.6

I have array of `Plan $plans`.
How to pass that array of $plans to my member controller?
Currently I use:
`* @param Plans|array $plan` in annotations

```
    public function findMembersByPlans( $planArray)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');
        $count = $queryBuilder->select('count(m)')
            ->leftJoin('mp.plan', 'p')
            ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->in('p.plan', ':planArray'))
            ->setParameters(
                [
                    'planArray'=> $planArray,
]);
```

How to get count of members? When I am Passing 1 Object. `Plan $plan` as parameter everything is ok.

Comment: Extract only ids from your planArray instead of using full objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
->leftJoin('mp.plan', 'p', Join::WITH, $queryBuilder->expr()->in('p.id', ':planIds'))
->setParameteter('planIds', array_map(
    function (Plan $plan) {
        return $plan->getId();
    }, $planArray
))
```

And you can remove the where clause.